# Maven expression for src/main/resources

Tags: maven-2

How can I specify the main resource directory in Maven as a File? I'm using `${project.resources[0]}`, but that is a `org.apache.maven.model.Resource`, whereas I need a `java.io.File`.

I need this for usage in the [rpm-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/):

```
<mapping>
  <directory>${app.home}/cfg</directory>
  <sources>
    <source>
       <location>${project.resources[0]}</location>
    </source>
   </sources>
</mapping>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, resources/[resource](http://maven.apache.org/ref/2.2.1/maven-model/maven.html#class_resource) is a `List<Resource>`. I may be wrong but I think that the best you can get from a [resource](http://maven.apache.org/ref/2.2.1/maven-model/maven.html#class_resource) is a String representing the directory where the resources are stored (which is a relative path to the POM).

```
${project.build.resources[0].directory}
```